# pytest + opencv + multiprocessing = segmentation error

Tags: python, opencv, pytest, python-multiprocessing

I am using opencv with multiprocessing. There is a module say a.py with class A inside which do something and another module b.py with class B which do something else. Module b has multiprocessing pool in it.

When I initialize instance of class B any number of time by importing the module in another file it works. 
When I run pytest using class B as fixture it fails by giving segmentation error but when the scope of fixture is changed to module level it works. And also in pytest only when test case of class A is running first, class B gives segmentation error but if class B is first and class A is second in pytest it runs without error.

Comment: Have you tried using a mutex?

Comment: Hi @attersson. Can you please explain me how to implement this? I'm using pool by passing pool object while initializing the class. Also, I'm new to multiprocessing.